# "template definition of non-template" error while using nested templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to have a nested template structure with a static variable inside. I've reduced my code to this barebones example.

```
template<typename T> struct A
{
    template<typename U> struct B
    {
        static const unsigned val;
    };
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
const unsigned A<T>::template B<U>::val;
```

This is giving me the error

```
template definition of non-template ‘const unsigned int A<T>::B<U>::val’
const unsigned A<T>::template B<U>::val;
```

I'm not able to find what exactly is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Dropping the "template" from your last line fixes it. But I won't make this an answer, because I have no idea why :s

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I guess it's not the correct context to use that keyword maybe.

Comment: I guess so. Still, B definitely looks like a dependent type template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `template` in the definition.  The symbol
`B` is not dependent, at least in the sense of the standard;
it's a locally declared name, since it is defined within the
template `A`.  See §14.6:

> Three kinds of names can be used within a template definition:
>
> — The name of the template itself, and names declared within the template itself.
>
> — Names dependent on a template-parameter (14.6.2).
>
> — Names from scopes which are visible within the template definition.

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename U>
const unsigned A<T>::B<U>::val;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why "template" keyword is invalid there? B is a dependant template.